# Displaying accents on the Linux console

Tags: linux, i18n

I'm trying to display ISO-8859-1 accents on a Linux console (vt).  This used to be as trivial as doing:

```
echo -e '\xe9'
```

By default in CentOS 6, the above displays a block.

If I run the following:

```
setfont lat1-16
echo -e '\xe9'
```

I get a reversed ? instead of the expected lowercase e acute accent.

If I run the following:

```
setfont iso01.16
```

I get a little house symbol.

I've messed around with various values -m and -u but that has zero effect on the output.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What is its character encoding?  If you're trying to output ISO-8859-1 to a UTF-8 or UTF-16 terminal emulator, this is the sort of behavior you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centos 7 (on my test virt, and presumably also Centos 6) tend to set UTF-8 by default, unless you told the installer otherwise, or reconfigured the system for some other encoding. `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` may indicate what language was set by the install:

```
# echo -e '\xe9' | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8
é
# locale
... (bunch of UTF-8 things here) ...
# grep lang /root/anaconda-ks.cfg
lang en_US.UTF-8
#
```

Unicodeness can be turned off via:

```
# unicode_stop
# setfont -m 8859-1
# echo -e '\xe9'
é
#
```

which hopefully is the same as on Centos 6. From some `grep`ing around in `/etc`, the files `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` or `/etc/locale.conf` look like they control the locale.

Comment: unicode_stop did the trick.  Why bother having char maps?